# Pool light not working

Tags: electrical, gfci, light, pool

Just bought a home and the only pool light is not working. If the GFCI breaker is not tripped and there is no outdoor switch or GFCI, does that mean it’s probably the bulb itself thats dead? Or could it be something else? Not sure what to check. Thanks

Comment: My switch is inside the house.

Comment: @chris, if this answer is helpful please upvote or accept (the check mark) this helps to close out the question and if accepted may help others.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a switch somewhere, possibly by the pumps and filters or by a door going out to the patio. Most pool lights are low voltage, 12 volt AC, and are fed from a transformer either in the control box for the pool or in a separate pedestal located at least 5 feet away from the pool's edge. You're going to have to find this first, then you can check for voltage at that point. If all checks out, then a bad bulb is probably at fault. If possible, try to get back with the previous owners about this or even some of your new neighbors with pools, they might have the same or similar systems.